# The mysterious : Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT

Tags: boot, grub2, login

I'm a long time LTS Ubuntu user, I recently changed my aging ASUS notebook to a Lenovo T450.

The latter came with windows 10, so I decided to wipe it with the fresh 16.04 Ubuntu.

The install (via a live usb image) went smoothly (or at least with no apparent problem), however, during  the subsequent boots, I get the error:

```
Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
```

Then I get the a console root login (no graphical login), when I log into my account I'm informed about some errors due to the system being mounted read-only.

I already did a search about this error so here's the summary:

1. I do not have dual boot, only a two-partitions ubuntu (40GB /, 200GB /home and no swap partition since I have 8GB ram).
2. I dot not have dual graphics, only the integrated intel 5500 (ironically i chose intel-only graphics to avoid any problems)
3. I did update my bios to the latest one (1.24 from 1.19)
4. If I force(though not advised) the file system to be mounted as rw instead of ro in the grub menu, I get into graphical login loop

I do not know what to do anymore, and I really do not want to change distribution so I hope someone here can help.